# GCD recursion function RTE in some IDEs

Tags: c++, recursion, ide, runtime-error

Trying to implement gcd int function using Euclidean Algorithm with recursion. Results from CodeBlocks differ from IDEone (which I use to test my code before submitting to a CP website, TLX: https://tlx.toki.id, which I assume has  similar compilers etc. because a lot of times IDEone and TLX got RTE while in CodeBlocks it ran without any problem). First Question: 1. Do they actually have something different that affects the output?

My first attempt was as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#define pass (void)0
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#define ll long long

int gcd(int x, int y){
    if(y!=0){
        gcd(y, x%y);
        //return x%y;
    } else {
        return x;
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << "test" << endl;
    int z = gcd(100, 10);
    cout << z << " bruh" << endl;
    cout << "hello" << endl;
}
```

which IDEone spits out

```
Runtime error #stdin #stdout 0.01s 5380KB
test
```

while it ran as expected (`z = 1` and prints out the correct stuff) in CodeBlocks

I tried to pinpoint where the error exactly occurs by 1. printing out at what part of the code my computer went error by the following way

```
void gcd(int x, int y){
    if(y!=0){
        cout << "if " << x << ", " << y << endl;
        gcd(y, x%y);
    } else {
        cout << "else " << x << ", " << y << endl;
        //return x;
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << "test" << endl;
    //int z = gcd(100, 10);
    gcd(100, 10);
    //cout << z << " bruh" << endl;
    cout << "hello" << endl;
}
```

which in both IDE, it outputted:

```
test
if 100, 10
else 10, 0
hello
```

then I also tried:

```
int gcd(int x, int y){
    if(y!=0){
        gcd(y, x%y);
        //return x%y;
    } else {
        return x;
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << "test" << endl;
    int z = gcd(100, 10);
    cout << z << " bruh" << endl;
    cout << "hello" << endl;
}
```

CodeBlocks outputted the first, while IDEone had an error as in the second

```
test
10 bruh
hello
```

```
Runtime error #stdin #stdout 0.01s 5380KB
test
```

from what I've tried and understand so far, it seems there's an error when the function gcd() calls the gcd() function. 2. Is my assumption correct? 3. and how am I supposed to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you declare a function to return a value, you *must* explicitly return a value, with the `return` statement. Otherwise you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: On another few notes, the initial code snippet uses way too many header files, which just aren't needed. And macros like `pass` or `ll` doesn't improve your code in any way, especially if you don't use them which just makes them irrelevant noise. And `using namespace std;` is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions; you're discarding the value from the recursion and not returning anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the recursive case of the `gcd()` function does not run a `return` statement. Thus, it should be modified like this:

```
int gcd(int x, int y){
    if(y!=0){
        return gcd(y, x%y);
    } else {
        return x;
    }
}
```

This could easily have been caught by enabling and reading [compiler warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings).